# nested field in Solr 5.2

Tags: indexing, nested, field, multivalue

I'm new to Solr and I have a very specific problem that I need to solve:
I have a csv file that contains my Solr document. Now, I do have a column (field) that's not only multiValued, but also contains 'subfields'
for example

```
"id":"0101",
"addMaterials":[{"name":"Mat1", "property":"prop1"},          
    {"name":"Mat2","property":"prop2"},
    {"name":"Mat3","property":"prop3"}],
"mainProperty":"mainproperty1",
"URL":"http://www.mySite..."
```

where id, addMaterials, mainProperty, and URL are my main fields while 'name' and 'property' are my subfields. I know that Solr is designed to handle denormalized documents but denormalizing is not a possible solution for my application.

What I'm thinking is to just separate my data set and move the fields (that have subfields) to another document and somehow make a new field to link it to the orginial document (e.g. fromIdField).

Is there any other solution to do this? My minimum goal is to index the values of addMaterials field (even without indexing the subfields)

from:

```
"addMaterials":[{"name":"Mat1", "property":"prop1"},          
    {"name":"Mat2","property":"prop2"},
    {"name":"Mat3","property":"prop3"}],
```

to

```
"addMaterials":{"name":"Mat1", "property":"prop1"}
"addMaterials":{"name":"Mat2", "property":"prop2"}
"addMaterials":{"name":"Mat3", "property":"prop3"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have found a solution to my problem. Instead of separating my data set, I kept the addMaterials field as a multiValued field and ignored the subfields. So I only have one multiValued field to be indexed. What I did was to use the update/ request of Solr to index my csv file and put },{ as my separator in my addMaterials multiValued field. The indexed document looks like this:

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem. Instead of separating my data set, I kept the addMaterials field as a multiValued field and ignored the subfields. So I only have one multiValued field to be indexed. What I did was to use the update/ request of Solr to index my csv file and put **},{** as my separator in my addMaterials multiValued field. The indexed document looks like this:

```
"addMaterials": ["[{\"name\":\"Mat1\", \"property\":\"prop1\"",
                 "\"name\":\"Mat2\", \"property\":\"prop2\"",
                 "\"name\":\"Mat3\", \"property\":\"prop3\"}]"]
```

I indexed my document using this:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/<coreName>/update/csv?
      stream.file=C:/userName/Solr/solr-5.2.0/documentFolder/myFile.csv&
      f.addMaterials.split=true&
      f.addMaterials.separator=\},\{&
      stream.contentType=text/plain;charset=utf-8"
```

Also, this assumes that the addMaterials field is a multiValued field. So make sure you modify your schema first before indexing your document using the procedure above. Otherwise, it will give an error saying that the f. is not a multiValued field.

Of course, if you need to query against the sub-fields then I guess you can use the !join command/function of Solr.